# Subscriber in RxJS

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, rxjs, angular-material

I am a newbie in angular, I am wondering what does the following code mean?

```
getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
}
```

I know what exactly it does, but I want to know this line specifically. 
heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5)
what gets assign where

This getHeroes() returns the sliced list of heroes at positions 1 and 5, returning only four of the Top Heroes (2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/observables check this bro

Answer (score 1):

Acoording to my undesrastndin if you want herso peoperty in your component to be available in your view for rendering. Then you need to assign it to what heroService.getHeroes return. However since heroService.getHeroes return an Observable. When you call it during assiging. You neeed to call the subsrcibe method.

Comment: where can I get the basics of Observable and subscribe function? I am kinda lagging

Comment: it a desigm pattern https://hackernoon.com/observer-vs-pub-sub-pattern-50d3b27f838c

Comment: Sure I will go through this, do let me know if you have more material for angular or this online angular documentation is useful https://angular.io/tutorial